# Group by and select in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to be able to group a list of items by a particular field (id) and then extract a dictionary of id,code pairs. I then need to access the id and code pairs to do some logic. how can i do this using linq?

e.g.

```
Id Code Send
1  500  1 
1  501  0
2  600  1
2  601  0
2  602  0
3  700  0
3  701  1
3  702  0
3  703  1
```

Expected Result -

```
1 500,501
2 600,601,602
3 700, 701, 702, 703
```

This is what i have so far - struggling to work out how to get just the codes into a dictionary:

```
from i in items 
group i by i.Id into g
select new Dictionary<Guid, List<long>>
   {
     g.Key, g.ToList()
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var res = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.Id)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.Select(v => v.Code).ToList()
    );
```

Your solution was close - you needed to add a selection of `Code` to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

the last part

```
g.ToList()
```

needs to be

```
g.Select(c => c.Code).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that LINQ has an operator that does this already.

```
ILookup<Guid, long> res = items.ToLookup(i => i.Id, i => i.Code);
```